# How to resolve union in Azure APIM synthetic GraphQL

Tags: graphql, azure-api-management

We are kind of experimenting with synthetic GraphQL in Azure APIM, using resolver policies. Up until now everything was working fine, but we want to introduce unions and so far no matter what and how we tried, we couldn't make the resolver work. Unfortunately we could find no usable documentation or tutorial/posts/etc on the internet (maybe just searching for the wrong stuff...).

If needed, I can provide a few examples and errors we've seen so far, but first I wanted to ask in general if anyone has any experience with APIM policies and unions or maybe some examples, that could help us out here.

---

As requested I will try to provide a few examples.

By default, when we only define the union itself in the schema like:

```
type Query {
    query1(attr: Int, ...): [ResultUnion]
}

type ResultDto {...}
type Error {...}
union ResultUnion = ResultDto | Error
```

And we have a very bvasic resolver like:

```
<http-data-spurce>
  <http-request>
    <set-method>GET</set-method>
    <set-url>@{...}</set-url>
    <set-header name="..." exist-action="override">
      <value>...</value>
    </set-header>
  </hhtp-request>
</http-data-source>
```

In this case when we try to use the query, we get an INVALID_CAST error:

```
"Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...]]'."
```

When we tried to manually map the response to either the result or error (in the http-response set-body tag), depending on what and how we tried, the errors differed, but before we implement anything custom, I would like to know how we should do it "by the book".

Comment: Please share some examples and error message you are getting